# Node js Azure media service api filestream not uploading

Tags: node.js, azure-media-services

I am trying to create asset in Azure media services using api v3 from node js.

```js
import {AzureMediaServices, Asset} from "@azure/arm-mediaservices";


const assetName = "English-class";
    const fileName = "/home/raju/work/dynamic-links/sample.mp4";
    const fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

    console.log("Uploading file to asset: " + assetName + ".. file size: " + fileSize);

    let newAsset = {
        storageAccountName: 'virtualclasses',
        // assetId : "97d52295-0fd7-4bb3-a3bf-edf6236366c9",
        description: "My first asset",
        options: {
            assetName,
            assetDescription: "My first asset",
            encodingType: "None",
            fileSize,
            fileName : 'sample.mp4',
            fileStream: fileStream,
            storageAccountType: "Standard_LRS",
            storageEncryptionFormat: "MP4",
        }
    } as Asset

    const asset = await mediaServicesClient.assets.createOrUpdate(resourceGroup, accountName, assetName, newAsset, {
        requestOptions: {
           onUploadProgress: (progress: any) => {
               console.log(progress);
               console.log(`Uploaded bytes: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);

           }
        },
        onResponse: (response: any) => {
            console.log(`Response received with status code: ${response.status}`);
            return response;
        },
    });
```

But file is not showing in the dashboard. After creating streaming locator, it is always showing **Your asset is either empty or not compatible for streaming. Please check your asset**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already walked through some of our Sample applications using the node.js and Typescript SDK here?

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/

Try the most basic encoding sample first.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264